# SharePoint server 2013 Error: The directory name is invalid

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i have an unknown error on SP site, it appear when accessing the Setting or a List in Site.
this is the error :
An error occurred during the compilation of the requested file, or one of its dependencies. Could not write to output file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\29890f08\3003d51b\App_Web_linksectionlevel1.ascx.b16d5c94.bqodwxos.dll' -- 'The directory name is invalid. ' 

Any help please

Comment: It happens because your application pool account does not have access to specified folder. Try to grant him this access.

Comment: i check the app pool everything is normal !

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be addressed by

1. stopping an IIS using the command IISrest /stop
2. navigate to the Folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files`
3. Delete all the files inside the Temporary ASP.NET Files (don't
   delete the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder itself!)
4. Start the IIS using the command IISresrt /start.

Your antivirus tries to scan each and every file like temp files, if we can exclude it, then this issue can be avoided as explained in MS article [Certain folders may have to be excluded from antivirus scanning when you use file-level antivirus software in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/952167/certain-folders-may-have-to-be-excluded-from-antivirus-scanning-when-y).